# InkCanvas Eraser

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, inkcanvas

I have sketchpad as `InkCanvas`; I want to change size of eraser so I've written:

```
Private Sub Sketchpad_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles Sketchpad.KeyDown

If e.Key = Key.OemMinus Then

' Decrease size of Eraser to 5*5 

Sketchpad.EraserShape = New RectangleStylusShape(5, 5)

End If

If e.Key = Key.OemPlus Then

' Increase size of Eraser to 50*50 

Sketchpad.EraserShape = New RectangleStylusShape(50, 50)

End If

If e.Key = Key.I Then
' Change editing mode to Ink
Sketchpad.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.Ink

End If

If e.Key = Key.E Then
' Change editing mode to Eraser
Sketchpad.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.EraseByPoint

End If

End Sub
```

Try this:

1. Select eraser by pressing e, Eraser stylusTip will appears Rectangular
2. Press + sign to increase size , you will not see any changes.  Why?
3. Now you press i to change editing mode, ink tip will appears.
4. Press e again to reswitch to Eraser. You will see that eraser shape has been changed.

Why not after pressing + sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.erasershape(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

"If you change the EraserShape, the cursor rendered on the InkCanvas is not updated until the next EditingMode change."

I tested the following code and it works fine:

```
if (e.Key == Key.OemMinus)
{
    ink.EraserShape = new RectangleStylusShape(5, 5);
    var editMode = ink.EditingMode;
    ink.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.None;
    ink.EditingMode = editMode;
}
if (e.Key == Key.OemPlus)
{
    ink.EraserShape = new RectangleStylusShape(50, 50);
    var editMode = ink.EditingMode;
    ink.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.None;
    ink.EditingMode = editMode;
}
```

Comment: But it is not the way it should work , eraser should reflect changes though we do not toggle editing mode as it works for ink shape.

ink.EraserShape = new RectangleStylusShape(5, 5);   

Should work , Why not working ???

Comment: You and I might not agree but it is in the MSDN so it is a known and intended functionality.